# Excel VBA Search + Sum Engine

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code a search + sum engine on Excel VBA. I have a list of entries, and what I need the code to do is search for a specific type of cost (for example "1 Equipment") and then it needs to sum all Equipment Costs and print it in a cell in another worksheet. Heres what I typed so far:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim fnd As String
Dim MyAr
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range, myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)

fnd = "1 Equipment"

MyAr = Split(fnd, "/")

For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=MyAr(i), after:=LastCell)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    End If
Set rng = FoundCell
        Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
            Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
                Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
            If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
        Loop

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
rng.**(____in here it needs to sum the value of the cell in 
the column to the right of where the word was found___)**

End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

This is the picture of my list of values (I only have a few values typed, but the engine has to go all the way to the end of the worksheet): 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPIc9.png
It needs to sum all the "1 Equipment" values and display the sum in another cell, so for this amount of entries, the answer would be 11750.

I am a beginner with excel VBA so I really need help. Thank you!

Comment: And SUMIFS() is not sufficient?

Comment: Why are you splitting `fnd = "1 Equipment"` by the "/" element and creating an array? What you are searching for is `fnd`, so `.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)`

Comment: Got it done with SUMIFS. Thank you!

Comment: If you still want to use `.Find` i did something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196583/vba-find-a-range-of-same-values-in-a-column-and-calculate-average/46197830#46197830) today. Just instead of the Average, you would want to display `SumValues` on `Debug.Print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that more like a custom function to be added to the sheet where you find all the cells corresponding to a given value and you sum up the adjacent cell numbers:

```
Public Function SumInvestments(ByVal InvType As String) As Long

    Dim allCells As Range
    Dim singleCell As Range
    Dim totalSum As Long

    Set allCells = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Find(InvType, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not allCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each singleCell In allCells
            totalSum = totalSum + singleCell.Offset(0,1).Value
        Next singleCell  
    End If
    SumInvestments = totalSum

End Function
```

To be used like this:

```
=SumInvestments("1 Equipment")
```

Comment: Though, I guess a SUMIFS() which is an Excel built-in function can do the trick too.

Comment: Yeah, I got it done with SUMIFS(). But thank you so much for your answer!